# Cannot create folders on external hdd drive although in the directory and owner

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ubuntu-touch

I don't know what happened, but I all of a sudden cannot write to my external drive anymore. It first said that

```
$sudo touch Data_Files
touch: cannot touch 'Data_Files': Read-only file system
```

When I do

```
$sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point
```

and do the same thing I get the error message

```
touch: cannot touch 'Data_Files': No such file or directory
```

Does anyone understand this behavior and know a solution?

Thanks.

Additional info belongs in the question, not in the comments.

`df -T` gives me:

```
/dev/sdb1 fuseblk 982013252 215741840 766271412 22% /media/paul/Volume
```

for the concerned drive.

`mount` renders

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/paul/Volume type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: Is your external drive formatted with NTFS, and do you share it with Windows? `df -T` will show you filesystem types. What messages come from the `mount` command?

Comment: df -T gives me:  /dev/sdb1      fuseblk  982013252 215741840 766271412  22% /media/paul/Volume for the concerned drive

Comment: mount renders /dev/sdb1 on /media/paul/Volume type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)

Comment: It is shared with Windows, but it worked fine for a long time, don't know what happened.

Comment: Possibly you unmounted it from Windows strangely? Or didn't unmount before shutting Windows down? Also, the `mount` results include `user_id=0,group_id=0` which should be your UID and GID (`id -n`).

Comment: I haven't used Windows in like a year.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix the user_id=0 and group_id=0?

Comment: Try `sudo mount -o remount,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) /dev/sdb1 /media/paul/Volume`

Comment: Unfortunately, this also does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the NTFS volume is dirty, damaged, or unplugged unsafely.

Find a Windows PC (Windows VM might work too, but not tested) and run the disk checker on the partition(s). Safely unmount, and reconnect to your Linux box. If it automatically mounts as rw, you're done. If not, you should try (again, on Windows) `chkdsk /F d:` in a command promt.

nb: Don't try your luck with Linux versions of ntfscheck or the likes, because they're just placeholders for future implementations that never happened.